# SQL injection order by not working

Tags: sql-injection

I made a vulnerable site for study on it. I try manual SQL injection on URL.
The URL is something like: `_localhost/profile.php?user=test_`.

If I put apostrophe in the URL I get error:

> *Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/html/profile.php on line 100*.

But when I try to find out the number of columns adding *ORDER BY 1--* and then increase the number until I get an error it doesn't work.
 **Not even** *ORDER BY 1000--* doesn't give me error.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, using `ORDER BY` with column position is deprecated in the ANSI SQL standard (see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/deprecated-sql-92-syntax/). But it's still supported by MySQL (but don't be surprised if it's removed in some future version someday).

I do get an error when I try to sort by the integer value 1000 (tested in MySQL 8.0):

```
mysql> select * from foo order by 1000;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '1000' in 'order clause'
```

But I don't get an error if I order by the *string* '1000':

```
mysql> select * from foo order by '1000';
```

So I'd guess that your code is quoting the input variable as it forms the `ORDER BY` clause.

It's legal SQL to use any constant value or constant expression in the `ORDER BY` clause. This is not an error, but since it will be the same value on every row in the result set, it's effectively a tie between all rows, and the order it produces will be arbitrary.